# How can I validate that my price contains a decimal point and two digits after the decimal

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

TO ensure that users don't enter a wrong price I want to force them to include the decimal point and two digits after the decimal point.

Here is what I have so far and it does not work

```
validates :price, :format => { :with =>  /\A\d+(([.])\d+)?z/ }, :numericality => {:message => "Please enter a valid price that includes a decimal"}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
\d+.\d\d
```